# Is there a way to keep my Mac terminal window always on top of other windows?

Tags: macos, terminal, mac

When I open a new Mac terminal window using spotlight search I automatically leave the current window to the desktop with new terminal window. I am forced to change windows to use terminal with other applications. What should I do?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're describing when you say "I am forced to change windows to use terminal with other applications". Can you explain a bit more what you're trying to do? There may be other ways.

Comment: Is the previous app in fullscreen? You can't have two apps in fullscreen, unless you use the Split function.